# Java Android translation animation - how to "take away" ImageView through bottom of the screen?

Tags: java, android, animation

I have and ImageView that is set on the bottom of the screen. 
I want to do an animation with translate to move it away through bottom side of the screen. now if to slide up I just need to set final Y point at -300 so I'll be sure that my ImageView slides up , how do I slide it down - is it possible to set in xml, or is it programmatically only?

Answer (score 0):

You can set positive y value in the code of translate anim.

translateAnimation(0,0,urView.getY,urViewgetY+300)